# How to pass the File Data from C# Console application to WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-post, console-application, httpcontent

I am trying to call the Web api method for saving the File Data.When I debug Webapi method I found that ContentLength is not coming as correct, because of this when i am retrieving the file it is showing error as corrupted file.

My Class method is :-

```
  using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
   {
     HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(file);
      formData.Add(stringContent, "file", file);
      formData.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(file.Length)), "ContentLength ");
      HttpResponseMessage responseFile = client.PostAsync("Report/SaveFile?docId=" + docId, formData).Result;
  }
```

My Web api method is :-

```
 [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage SaveFile(long docId)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            try
            {
                var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
                bool IsSuccess = true;
                if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
                {
                    var docfiles = new List<string>();
                    foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                    {
                        HttpPostedFile postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                        // Initialize the stream.
                        Stream myStream = postedFile.InputStream;
                        myStream.Position = 0;
                        myStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        var _item = CorrectedReportLibrary.Services.ReportService.SaveFile(myStream,docId);
                        response = Request.CreateResponse<bool>((IsSuccess)
                                                                      ? HttpStatusCode.OK
                                                                      : HttpStatusCode.NoContent,
                                                                  IsSuccess);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Theranos.Common.Library.Util.LogManager.AddLog(ex, "Error in CorrectedReportAPI.Controllers.SaveDocument()", null);
                return Request.CreateResponse<ReportDocumentResult>(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, null);

            }
            return response;
        }
```

How can I set the `ContentLength` from C# class method?

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit strange that you use `ContentLength` as the second parameter on the `StringContent` class. It is suppose to be which encoding you want to use, for example 
`new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8)`. I don't think it is the content length that is the issue here.

[StringContent class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158992(v=vs.118).aspx)

I guess since it is a file you want to upload, you already have the file read as a stream, so I usually do something like this:

Client:

```
private async Task UploadFile(MemoryStream file)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new StreamContent(file));
    var result = await client.PostAsync("Report/SaveFile?docId=" + docId, content);
}
```

Edit. Since it's a multipartform it's easier to let the framework handle the details. Try something like this:

Server:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SaveFile(long docId)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    try
    {
        var filedata = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider());
        foreach(var file in filedata.Contents)
        {
            var fileStream = await file.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        }

        response = Request.CreateResponse<bool>(HttpStatusCode.OK, true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response = Request.CreateResponse<bool>(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, false);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Below Code I added as you told but still same issue coming that ids file is corrupted: contents.Add(new StreamContent(stre),"file",file);
                                            var result = await client.PostAsync("ReportInfo/SaveFile?docId=" + docId, contents);

Comment: @gorakh Updated with server side example

Answer (score 0):

> At Last I found the solution no need to change the web api service,
>   issue was from client where I was directly passing the file data, Now the modified
>   working code is like this:-

```
 using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
 {
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
     formData.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(bytes)), "file", file);
     HttpResponseMessage responseFile = client.PostAsync("ReportInfo/SaveFile?docId=" + docId, formData).Result;
 }
```